# What are the characters saying in the first few minutes of Assassins Creed?

Tags: dialogue, translation, assassins-creed

The movie Assassins Creed starts out with a scene in Spain in which the characters are having a 5-minute conversation in Spanish. Is anyone able to translate/explain this for me?

Comment: Weren't there subtitles? I don't remember not being able to understand what was happening.

Comment: @Darren, could be a pirated version lacking the subtitles.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths wouldn’t blame them if it was. If I’d paid to see that dross I’d ask for my money back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transcribed from the version on Now TV:

> The inquisition has finally delivered Spain to the Templars. Sultan
>   Muhammad and his people still hold out in Granada. But if his son, the
>   Prince is captured... he will surrender the city and the Apple of
>   Eden. Do you Aguilar De Nerha swear to honor our Order in the fight
>   for freedom? To defend mankind against the Templar's tyranny and
>   preserve free will?
>
> I swear.
>
> If the Apple falls into their hands the Templars will destroy
>   everything that stands in their way. Protest, dissent, our right to
>   think for ourselves... Swear to me that you will sacrifice your life
>   and the lives of everyone here to keep it from them.
>
> Yes, mentor.
>
> Our own lives are nothing. The Apple is everything. The spirit of the
>   eagle, will watch over the future.
>
> Where other men blindly follow the truth remember... Nothing is true.
>   Where other men are limited by morality or law remember... Everything
>   is permitted. We work in the dark to serve the light. We are
>   Assassins.